# How to execute FOR loop in robot file?

Tags: for-loop, robotframework

```
val = 12

:FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE   ${val}
Run Keyword If  condition1 or condition2  Call_Keyword  ${val1}  {val2}
Run Keyword If  condition3  exit for loop
```

I am using this snippet test.robot file, but it says as

> FOR loop contains no keywords.

I do not understand. what's wrong in this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to indent the keywords in the loop, e.g. to mark them as "the looped over block".
As explained in [the user guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#normal-for-loop),

> The keywords used in the for loop are on the following rows and they must be indented one cell to the right. When using the plain text format, the indented cells must be escaped with a backslash, ...

So in your case, as of 2017, it should be:

```
:FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE   ${val}
\        Run Keyword If  condition1 or condition2  Call_Keyword  ${val1}  {val2}
\        Run Keyword If  condition3  exit for loop
```

In the newer version of the framework this syntax is deprecated, and uses a block ended with the `END` keyword:

```
FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE   ${val}
        Run Keyword If  condition1 or condition2  Call_Keyword  ${val1}  {val2}
        Run Keyword If  condition3  exit for loop
END
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning it. Sorry, I missed it.

Comment: The backslashes were eventually deprecated in favor of an `END` keyword to mark the `END` of the block. See latest docs at http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#for-loops

Comment: @Todor Minakov  It would be good if you could update your solution as indicated by MarkHu comment and jeanpic answer.

Comment: @GenericRatzlaugh thanks, updated it; my answer was context specific (for a contextual question ;)), applicable in 2017 but nowadays it really is different.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to indent the keywords in the loop, e.g. to mark them as "the looped over block".
As explained in [the user guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#normal-for-loop),

> The keywords used in the for loop are on the following rows and they must be indented one cell to the right. When using the plain text format, the indented cells must be escaped with a backslash, ...

So in your case, it should be:

```
${startValue}    Set Variable    0    #    initial value

${endvalue}    Set Variable    12    #    End Value

${Step}    Set Variable    1    #    step value

:FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    ${startvalue}    ${endvalue}    step=${step}

\        Run Keyword If  condition1 or condition2  Call_Keyword  ${val1}  {val2}
\        Run Keyword If  condition3  exit for loop
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [user guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#for-in-range-loop), a correct for-in-range loop in Robot Framework 3.2+ would be the following:

```
FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE   ${val}
    Run Keyword If    condition1 or condition2    Call_Keyword    ${val1}    {val2}
    Run Keyword If    condition3    exit for loop
END
```